# How can I compare the output of a command, (the output is a number) to a number? Trying to see if the output is greater than or equal to 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to run a script that essentially runs `psg defunct | wc -l` and gives output depending on if the output of that is greater than or equal to 1 or not.

However, I can't get the `-ge` flag to work to do so. I was wondering if anyone has any input as to what I'm doing wrong, and if you could help me correct it.

Here's the current script:

```
 #!/bin/bash -x
 export LANG="C"
 #
 # Created by Blake Smreker | b0s00dg
 # Purpose is to assist users with defunct process tickets
 #
 #

 menu ()
 {
 echo "What is the server name?"
 read srvrname
 badboi=$"$srvrname"
 }

 vars ()
 {
 psgwc=$"/u/bin/psg defunct | wc -l"
 psgd=$"/u/bin/psg defunct"
 die=$"/bin/kill -9 `psg defunct | awk '{print $3}'`"
 belowmsg=$'echo The number of defunct processes is below threshold! Resolve the ticket and put the following in the ticket:'
 abovemsg=$'echo There is more than 100 zombies! Getting you more information:'
 }

 connect ()
 {
 connectme="/usr/bin/dzdo -u oseho /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$badboi"
 }

 main ()
      {
 ${connectme} ". /u/data/environment; $psgwc"

 if ${connectme} $psgwc -ge 1
 then
     $abovemsg
     echo "Determine the owner of the below process. Then copy and paste the below, and send it to the team on Service Now."
     echo "psg defunct | wc -l:"
     ${connectme} $psgwc
     ${connectme} $psgd
 else
     $belowmsg
     echo "psg defunct | wc -l:"
     ${connectme} $psgwc
 fi
 }

 menu
 vars
 connect
 main
```

And here is the error message:

```
+ /usr/bin/dzdo -u oseho /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@oses4101 /u/bin/psg defunct '|' wc -l -ge 1
wc: illegal option -- g
usage: wc [-c | -m | -C] [-lw] [file ...]
```

It seems to think that me putting `-ge` is apart of me using `wc`. However, when I try to correct it, it doesn't work.

The issue lies in the if statement towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the output of `psg defunct | wc -l` into a file, then using the file in `test` worked:

```
[ $(cat outputfile) -ge 1]
```

allowed the output file to be a number in this way.